# dired-icon not show icons in dired-subtree

Tags: dired

```
Linux  Mint 20
Emacs 27.1
package: dired, dired+, dired-icon
```

[dired-icon](https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-icon)

In folder Temp has:

Folder:

```
MyFolder
```

Files:

```
someFile.txt
someFile2.txt
```

In folder `MyFolder` has:
Folders:

```
mySubFolder_1
mySubFolder_1_1
```

Files:

```
myfile_1_1.txt
myfile_1.txt
myfile.txt
```

In dired mode I open folder Temp. Go to folder `MyFolder` and press `ENTER`.
As result open folder `MyFolder`. And folders and files icons correct show.

Here result:

[image]
Nice.
Now I again open folder Temp.
A I want to use command `dired-subtree-toggle` to open folder `Temp`.

```
M-x dired-subtree-toggle
```

And here result.
[image]
[image]

As you can see now **NOT show icons** of folders and files.